# Strange error when serving Vue after turning of the screen

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, yarnpkg, vue-cli

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec.js 1:3
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this binary file)

This happens when I turn off the screen of the laptop for a while

I tried uninstall / re-install Node, NPM Several Times

and now I tried to use Yarn but still the same problem happens

[image: the erro]

Comment: Seems to me like it's a node configuration issue.

Comment: It could be the `core-js` upgraded and caused the break. Have you tried to install `core-js` module to test? If it works after install `core-js`, you need to find out which of your package using `core-js`. In my case, it was the `apollo-koa-server` which using old `core-js` caused some annoying problem, and I had to digged down 999+ github issues to find out....

Comment: Btw, it's great if you could share some of the way to reproduce your problem, it makes people find out reason easier.

Comment: Please copy paste error messages instead of screenshoting them